# Updating value of variable in Node js promise function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to update value of a variable inside the promise function. What am I doing wrong?

```js
var data="valueoutside";

wb.xlsx.readFile(filePath).then(function(){

data="new value";
}
);

console.log(data); 
//shows 'valueoutside' as output and not 'new value'
```

Comment: `readFile` is asynchronous thus `console.log` is executed before `then` is fired

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`readFile` is asynchronous, therefore `console.log(data)` is called before `readFile` has a chance to finish running and updating the value.

Change your code to this and it will work:

```
var data="valueoutside";

wb.xlsx.readFile(filePath).then(function() {
    data="new value";
    console.log(data); 
});
```

Another option would be to use a synchronous call:

```
var data="valueoutside";
var contents = wb.xlsx.readFileSync(filePath);

data="new value";

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your `console.log(data)` into the `then` handler, and you'll see the updated value.

```
var data="valueoutside";

wb.xlsx.readFile(filePath).then(function(){
    data="new value";
    console.log(data);
});
```

The function inside the `then` handler will execute once the promise resolves.

Answer (score 0):

ReadFile is asynchronous function. So you should write console.log in then function

```
var data="valueoutside";

wb.xlsx.readFile(filePath).then(function(){
   data="new value";
   console.log(data);
});
```